# Como deletar dados de uma tabela relacionada com outra

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Eu tenho a seguinte situação com um método de deletar diretorio:

```
internal void DeleteDiretorio(Model.Diretorio diretorio)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TESTEntities())
        {
            var dir = ctx.DIRETORIO.FirstOrDefault(a => a.DIRETORIO_GUID == diretorio.DIRETORIO_GUID);
            if (dir == null)
                throw new ArquivoException("Diretorio não encontrado");
            ctx.Entry(dir).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
```

Esse método é pra deletar de acordo pelo id,mas Diretório ele tem uma lista de arquivos então ele não permite deletar, como ficaria esse método no EF para deletar com todos os arquivos vinculados ao diretório?

Comment: Em caso de relacionamentos entre entidades, o delete deve ser por cascata.

Comment: E então como ficaria no meu caso Usando EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nas suas classes de entidade, nos objetos de navegação, basta usar o Data Annotation `[Required]`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public class Produto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

Se estiver utilizando mapeamentos com o EntityTypeConfiguration, pode usar o WillCascadeOnDelete:

```
HasRequired(t => t.Categoria)
  .WithMany(m => m.Produtos)
  .HasForeignKey(d => d.id)
  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: na minha camada de modelo? no caso eu colaria [Required] no meu List<Arquivo> arquivosLista   ?

Comment: Depende muito de como foi implementada a sua aplicação, se voce tiver usado Data Annotations essa é uma opção, mais se vc tiver utilizado mapeamentos com o EntityTypeConfiguration, tem como fazer isso no mapeamento, utilzando o WillCascadeOnDelete

Comment: Eu uso uma classe estendendo de DbContext, com os metodos DbSet:

Comment: public DbSet<DIRETORIO> DIRETORIO { get; set; }

Comment: Este objeto DbSet é o objeto de mapeamento dentro do contexto (DbContext). Se vc utilizar Data Annotations você tem que incluir os atributos dentro da sua classe DIRETORIO, ou na classe ARQUIVOS. Dê uma estudada na utilização de Data Annotations no link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx a segunda opção que lhe repasse é para a utilização de mapeamento com FluentAPI, dê uma olhada no link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: o Arquiteto aqui do projeto falou que ia ver esse contexto depois e que eu não precisava implementar isso agora, de qualquer forma sua resposta foi de grande ajuda.